# How to speed up the build of front-end monorepo projects?

Tags: frontend, monorepo

> Here are some of my current thoughts, but would also like to understand how the community is doing it now

### Use caching to reduce build time

Motivation

Currently, every time you change something in the libs, someone else needs to `initialize` it again when pulling it through git. If you know which package it's in, you can just run the `initialize` command for the specified package. If you don't know, you need to run the root `initialize` command, which is actually very slow because it re-runs all npm packages that contain the `intialize` command, regardless of whether they have changed or not.

1. reduce initialize time and improve collaborative development experience
2. support for ci/cd caching of built libs to speed up build time

Current state

- `lerna run`

  - First initialization of new project 198.54s
  - Re-initialize for non-new projects 90.17s

Requirements

- Execute commands as concurrently as possible according to the dependency graph, and implement caching based on git changes
- Execute commands in modules that specify module dependencies
- Execute commands in all submodules

Implementation ideas

> lerna api is currently severely undocumented: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2013

1. scan lerna.json for all modules
2. run the specified commands in parallel as much as possible according to the dependencies
3. check git when running the command to see if it needs to be skipped

Schematic: https://photos.app.goo.gl/aMyaewgJxkQMhe1q6

---

- The [ultra-runner](https://github.com/folke/ultra-runner) already exists, so maybe it's better to support this feature based on it

  - There seems to be no support for running commands other than `build` at the moment, see: https://github.com/folke/ultra-runner/issues/224

---

Known solutions

- Trying to use Microsoft rush -- hoping for a better solution without replacing the main framework lerna+yarn

Comment: Finally, I built my own plug-in using yarn2 plugin api to complete this work, refer to: https://github.com/rxliuli/liuli-tools/tree/master/libs/yarn-plugin-changed